# Go-ethereum full node uses 32 GB memory

Tags: go-ethereum

My Go-ethereum full node constantly uses 98% of the available 32 GB RAM on my Windows computer, is this normal? Go-ethereum specs says that you only need 16 GB. Should I buy more memory or is Go-ethereum always using 98% the memory available no matter how much I buy? I ask bc I would like to install additional software on that computer that could use 10 GB RAM leaving just 22 GB for Go-ethereum and I don't want to introduce any low RAM problems.